# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

Tags: eloquent, echo, builder

This strange thing is happening to me.I have the code below :

```
$state_image =States_Images::where('id_state', $id);
echo $delete_path=$state_image->name;
```

and the result is :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$name
```

Someone help me pls :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to finish the query with get() or first(). In your case probably:

```
States_Images::where('id_state', $id)->first();
```