# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$sessionId

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, orm

This is my PlayerController, Player & Session Model and Resource.

I want to use the input (sessionId from SessionsTable) to fetch user from the room with the same id (userSession) and return an array in this format: [{userId:1, userName: stacki, userVote:8},{...},...]

I already asked [here][1] to achieve this and now im stuck with this error.
What do I have to change in order to solve this issue? Simply adding ->first() does not solve my issue, I need more than one record.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Player;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\Players as PlayerResource;

class PlayerController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $room = $request->input('sessionId');

        $currentPlayers = Player::where('userSession', $room)->get();

        return PlayerResource::collection($currentPlayers);

    }




    public function create()
    { }


    public function update()
    { }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    public $sortable = [
        'userId',
        'userName',
        'userVote'
    ];

    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
    }

    public function players(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Session');
    }

}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Session extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Player');

    }
    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Player', 'userId');
    }
}

class Players extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'userId' => $this->sessionId,
            'userName' => $this->userName,
            'userVote' => $this->userVote
        ];
    }
}

`


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062014/display-db-entries-in-json-array-in-controller-laravel-php
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144564/undefined-property-illuminate-database-eloquent-builder)

Comment: that's no duplicate simply adding ->first() is not solving my issue at all

Comment: Where is `$this->sessionId` coming from?

Comment: Class `Players` needs to extend `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource` in order to be able to access the model's properties

Answer (score 2):

Your `Player` class might extends the `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource` instead of `ResourceCollection`.

This should solve your problem.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Players extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'userId' => $this->sessionId,
            'userName' => $this->userName,
            'userVote' => $this->userVote
        ];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.